# To connect to Remote Desktop connection via local system

Tags: java, localhost, remote-server

I am able to login to the dedicated server from a local system by Remote Desktop connection. I used IP address and admin password to login dedicated server. I ran WebSphere server in dedicated server and deployed my application then I can access my application from dedicated server's browser like

```
localhost:8080/myapp
```

or

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/myapp
```

It was working fine there, but when I tried to access the same app from my local system as

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/myapp
```

It doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: How is this related to java?? My first guess is that the server has blocked inbound connections on port 8080. If so, you either have to allow it or change the webserver to listen on another port.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps (mentioned [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7))

1.Open Windows Firewall by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type firewall, and then click Windows Firewall.

2.In the left pane, click Advanced settings. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

3.In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialog box, in the left pane, click Inbound Rules, and then, in the right pane, click New Rule.

4.Follow the instructions in the New Inbound Rule wizard( Open port,8080).